# How to display only selected fields (from checkboxes) of a SQL Server database data on a datagridview control through linq query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datagridview

I have a database for vehicle details. I want to read the database and display only the checked fields through checkbox controls as on the attached image, on to a DataGridView control. So the datagridview value changes as I check different checkboxes. How can I do this with using linq query? Thank you very much guys.

[My Windows Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWAmv.png)

```
var vlist = from lst in dc.tblVhcleInfos
            select lst;
dataGridView1.DataSource = vlist;
```

Comment: Dynamically created query may help you. See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Select all the columns and bind to data grid view. Hide/show the columns based on the checkbox values. This would be the one of easiest approach.

Comment: It's easy, but it may not be effective if there are many columns.